# Posting data with angularjs v 1.3

Tags: angularjs, resources, http-post, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api 2.0 application and I have to post data of a form.. Here my js code:

```
(function (angular) {
    var public_area = angular.module("public-area", ['ngResource']);

    public_area.factory("MyService", function ($resource) {
        return {
            my_controller: $resource("/api/MyHttpControllerTest/")
        };
    });

    public_area.controller("MyController", function ($scope, MyService) {
        $scope.getPlans = function ()
        {
            var pianiTariffari =
                new MyService
                    .my_controller
                    .query({
                        customerType: $scope.customerType
                    }, isArray = true);
        }

        $scope.sendInvitation = function ( )
        {
            var invitation =
                 new MyService
                    .my_controller(
                        {
                            request: {
                                CustomerType: "test"
                            }
                        });

            invitation.$save();
        }
    });
})(angular);
```

How you can see, I have a controller.. and two function, 1 in GET and 1 in POST...

I see you also the server side controller

```
public FillFormPresentaUnAmicoResponse GetPromozioni(string customerType)
    {
        ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public PresentaUnAmicoResponse InvitaAmico(PresentaUnAmicoRequest request)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Where the class PresentaUnAmicoRequest is

```
public class PresentaUnAmicoRequest
{
    public string CustomerType { get; set; }
}
```

The GET function works correctly! But the POST not...
In the post I receive a valid instance of the "request", bu the property inside it is NULL...

The really strange thing to me is that if I call the Post method in this way:

```
var invitation = new MyService.my_controller(undefined);
invitation.$save();
```

server side, the "request" is instanced.. I expected "request = null" instead..

Can anyone help me?
Thank you

UPDATE:

[image]

If I understood, I need always the same object to stick REST principles. So, according to spike's example I believe I have to create an object similar to this:

```
public class Promos
{
   public string CustomerType{ get; set; }
   public List<string> PromoPerCustomerType{ get; set; }
}

public class PresentaAmico 
{
    public Promos Promozioni { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And my Rest service should be like this

```
[HttpGet]
public PresentaAmico Get(string customerType)
{
     ...
}

[HttpPost] 
public void Save(PresentaAmico myForm)
{
     ...
}
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO This is not the way the $resouce is works at its best and that's because you're not really sticking to REST principles. The idea of $resource, is to get an object, modify it and then $save it again, which maps to a GET and POST calls in which the object that comes back and is being sent, are the same.

You are GETting an FillFormPresentaUnAmicoResponse and POSTing another type of object, namely a PresentaUnAmicoResponse.

Which of course could start the whole discussion whether you are using REST as it would work with WebAPI: namely a resource, which you modify by mapping the HTTP verbs on it ( GET/POST etc. ) Your controller doesn't really stick to those rules since you send different types of objects over the wire.

So I would actually recommend 2 controllers, one for each of your types: FillFormPresentaUnAmicoResponseController and a PresentaUnAmicoResponseController. I would also reconsider the naming in this case - there's no need in the 'response' suffix.

```
var presenta = $resource('/presentaunamicoresponse/:id', { id:'@id'});
// The id doesn't make any sense here - which should raise the question on
// whether these stuff is really suitable for REST or whether you are really
// doing a remote procedure call, but OK.
presenta.CustomerType = 'Whatever';
presenta.$save();
```

I think this is how it would work. You would have to stick it in your factory though for consistency. But as you can see in the docs ( https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource ) - you get the resouce, and manipulate properties on the resource itself. Then you call the $save() method on it.

Comment: Yes... I had some doubts when I was reading a guide about angularjs and resources... Now my doubts are clear... surely I miss important notions about REST.. I have done a test.. 1 controller, 1 object as you had told me, and infact it works now! But that was a test, and that is not my solution.. I still have a doubt about your solution too... But i need to explain the context. I have a dropdown and when I select a value another drop must be filled. I think have 2 controllers would work but perhpas is not the solution this time. What do you suggest? Using get/post instead of resources?

Comment: Could you give me a bit more information on the domain? You are getting promozioni - which are special offers I suppose - and you want to invite a friend or something? Sorry my italian ( if it is italian ) is very bad.

Comment: Yes, I have this really simple application. Just 1 form: "Invite a friend".. In this form I have some textbox (not important), 1 dropdownlist where i can select customer type (Biz or not), and 1 dropdownlist that is filled with special offers for business or private, based on previous selection.
So user selects customer type and the application do a call to the controller to obtain special offer for that customer type. 
Then user continue to fill the form and in the end click on a link (that is not a submit) and I do a call (in POST) to the controller to save on db the invitation.

Comment: I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jctzqdcv/1/ - does that work for you? In case of cascading dropdowns - returning a tree structure worked really well for me. You just need one GET call for that to make that work. I'm sorry I didn't use $resource, I can do that too if you like. Let me know.

Comment: Ohh thank you.. really... You are too kind :) No, that's ok.. I can try by myself to transform you example using $resource...
Just 2 questions:
1. I've updated my question, can you confirm I have understood everything good, please?
2. I understood your example works really good with cascading dropdowns. But what if I had radio button, and when I had selected it, the dropdown was filled? The update I did in the post is still valid?
Thank you

Comment: 1 - Yes I think you did, although you could add the wrapping controller for clarity. The original REST document is here, it may be interesting for you. http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm. Furthermore, WebAPI works a lot by convention. So if you just call your methods Get and Post, you don't need the attributes. And as an added bonus I created a radio button example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/jctzqdcv/2/ - note the $parent in the ng-model of the ng-repeat. Here's why: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/06/25/radio-buttons-with-angularjs.aspx

Comment: Thak you, you are really fantastic... Both the solution and the explanations an the link

Comment: please can you let me see just the post with resource? If I do `$http.post('/api/PresentaUnAmico/',$scope.pianiTariffari[0]).success(function () {});` works fine... If I do `var invitation = new PresentaUnAmicoService.piani_tariffari({ request: $scope.pianiTariffari[0] }).$save();`, I have always the same problem... the property inside my object are null

Comment: @Ciccio: I hadn't worked with $resource before so I decided to give it a try: https://github.com/jochenvanwylick/SODemoAngularResourceWebAPI . Check out application.js to see how I think $resource could be used against WebAPI

Comment: Thank you... but in the end this link helped me really much with resource... perhaps it can be useful to you too.. http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/